# Why does inductor exhibits not symmetrical current behavior?

Tags: pwm, inductor

I am modelling a PWM switching whose model is shown here below, where the Pulse generator represents my previous PWM stage.
[image]

So far, I am experiencing some weird behaviour in the inductor, I see how it does not exhibits a symmetrical behaviour in its current, as in show below when showing the input to the MOSFET and the output after the filter

[image]

I wonder why does this happen, is it owed to how it was modelled? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Regards!

---

Focusing in the inductor current ,I_L,  ** it is shown that there is not symmetry in the current in the Y axe (A) coloured in red**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you consider to be wrong?

Comment: Why would it be symetrical? The current from the primary during the "charging"/up-slope phase is determined by the input voltage and the "discharge"/down-slope is determined by the output voltage, both for a given inductance value.

Comment: @Andyaka What I would expect is that the Vout averaged slope is the same as the one of Vin while discharging

Comment: @winny shouldn't the peak of Vout start decreasing at the same time at the one of Vin?

Comment: @ndarkness You seem confused. Measure the inductor current. "Vin averaged" vs. "Vout averaged" does not make any sense. The inductor current is the inductor current. Are you trying to measure the input voltage ripple?

Comment: @winny No Winny I wan to see the distortion of my signal once recovered from PWM, thus Vin avareage and Vout average are the signal at input of the mosfet and at the load. Those are the voltages. What I see is that in the inductor itself, last picture, the current seems not to be symmetrical from the Y axis (A)

Comment: With limited bandwidth it will always look round and you will always have delay.

Comment: @winny I am a bit more concern to the fact hat Vout average does not have the same discharning slope that Vin average as I would assume rather than it conserve the shape :)

Comment: The apparent slope difference is caused by your input and output waveforms having different scales. Output voltage should be normalized from 14V (maximum output voltage range) not the peak-to-peak voltage of the output waveform (which is reduced due to low-pass filtering).

Comment: Filters have both a phase delay and a finite bandwidth, sharp edges need infinite bandwidth to be properly reproduced in real life. Your waveform "Vin averaged" has a ramp on both the rising *and* falling edges because it's impossible to have a signal with a perfectly vertical edge in reality (finite bandwidth) and the signal "Vout averaged" has delay because all filters add delay and it's got the shape it's got because inductive filters work better at higher currents (more filtering = rounded), but at the lower currents the filter uh...  "filters" less so the output looks more like the input.

Comment: Oh and please label **where** in the schematic each waveform is supposed to be. I don't see "Vin averaged" or "Vout averaged" on that schematic anywhere and don't expect too many comprehensive answers until that's fixed as we're not mind readers, for us to understand what's happening we need to know... what's happening. Clearly indicating which point in the circuit corresponds to which waveform helps an awful lot in aiding our ability to work out *what on earth's actually happening*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick simulation of a classic LR low pass filter fed with an asymmetrical sawtooth wave form: -

[image]

Sawtooth rise time is 20 us and fall time is 80 us. Period is 100 us. Note that I just used numbers that were conveneient and I wasn't trying to exactly simulate your circuit. The result is typical of an LR LPF.

This looks just like what you are describing so, if you are still not convinced, please expain what facet of the waveform in your question is not described here.

Comment: if you compare your outcome signals with my first figure, you can see that I have a different slope in Vout averaged and Vin averaged while discharging, whereas you have the same slope while discharging. That's wat doesn't convince me ;)

Comment: The key concept here is that the inductor current is proportional to the integral of its applied terminal voltage. Thinking about it the other way around, the voltage is the derivative (slope) of the current. The slope of the current does indeed start to reduce as soon as the voltage starts reducing, but it's still rising, so the actual peak of the current is delayed until the inductor terminal voltage passes through zero.

Comment: @ndarkness I don't fully understand where Vin (averaged) comes from or how you calculated it. Maybe you should give details about this if it is some numerical average through some form of digital filtering?

Comment: @ndarkness I don't see Vin (averaged) as a measurement node on your schematic so this adds to the lack of clarity in your question.

Comment: Ok I will do it in a different way, I have replicated @Andyaka circuit so it looks like [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/65042/inductor%20params.png) where the output signals are [these](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/65043/Untitled.png) and as [you see](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/65044/output.png) the voltage in the inductor seems to be different accross its terminals

Comment: @ndarkness stop wasting my time with a new circuit and a new set of waveforms. Please answer where on the original circuit Vin (averaged) is and how it is manipulated. I'm not going to look at your new waveforms because I do this for free and it's just not that important to me. You play the game and you will get an answer or, expect your question to be down voted and possibly closed. PLEASE EXPLAIN where Vin (averaged) comes from.

Comment: @Andyaka, I think that threating is not the best way... I showed in the other way in order to simplify the circuit and because I cannot add any link more to the original post...Vin(averaged) is just an average with a FIR filter of the input voltage at the gate of the NMOS, Vout(Averaged) is the same FIR filter applied to the output voltage ( output of the filter)

Comment: So, you are not even using a signal that is the actual PWM input to the inductor but something that is one transistor further back - what do you expect - MOSFETs have all sorts of nuances. Inductors: V = L\$\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ - that's all you need to know. Everything else can be derived.

Comment: @Andyaka, I think this is going badly for a reason that I cannot understand... Maybe my English is not good enough. I do have a PWM input signal (Vin) that goes into the MOSFETs gates to make them commute or not, then a classic LR filter that filters the output of the MOSFETs  and it should produce my original input signal (this filtered output is called Vout). AFTER THAT, I do an average of those signals ( Vout and Vin ) to check whether they resemble themselves or not, this averaged signals are Vout(averaged) and Vin(averaged). I DO NOT put Vin averaged into the MOSFET gates.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what it is you are not understanding because an inductor is an inductor and behaves as an inductor yet you seem to be confused by that. Maybe delete your question and start again but keep it simple and specific. I'm not going to go through all this again.

Comment: My question is quite straightforward, I want to know, why in my third picture, I do see a shift in the inductor current from the Y axis, denoted by the small red lines.

Comment: @ndarkness For exactly the same reason as there is a delay in inductor current in my picture. Look at my picture and ask yourself is there anything there that you don't understand or confuses you. At least that way we can get rid of the native and fundamental inductor general questions wihout having to worry about this implementation or that implementation.